# How do I make a widget with the same size as an image in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to have a banner on the bottom of my application which scales with varying width. However, I can't get the size of the widget to correspond to the size of the image and because of that, I leave some blank space underneath the banner itself. How can this be done?

Here my try:

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#6ec4c1")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.95}
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        ImageButton:
            source: "images/back_arrow.png"
            on_release: app.change_screen("home_screen")
        Image:
            source: "images/icon.png"
        Label:
            text: ""
    Image:
        id: banner
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint: 1, None
        source: "images/banner.png"
```

This code does place the picture at the bottom! But ideally, I'd like to have it stay at the bottom with full-screen width and scale in y to fit it. Is this possible?

[What I want and it only works for this specific aspect ratio of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47p4X.png)

[When I change the width of the screen I'd like it to scale in y to fit the screen instead it keeps y constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIvUb.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I added the code i've tried but I don't really know how to get the banner at the bottom as I know the Image: fills the image to the entire screen. How could I get around that

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `size_hint` of any `Widget` is `(1,1)`. which means that your `Image` will be the same size as its containing `FloatLayout`. So you can set values for `size_hint`, or you can set `size_hint: None, None` and then provide values for `size`. Also, `pos_hint: {"bottom": 1}` will not work, since `bottom` is not a supported key for `pos_hint`. If you want the `Image` at the bottom, use `pos_hint: {'y':0}`, but the default value for `pos` is `(0,0)`, so you shouldn't even need the `pos_hint: {'y':0}`.

Also, if you set a `size_hint` to `None` without providing the corresponding `width` or `height`, then the default `width` or `height` (which is `100`) will be used.

I think I am finally getting what you want. You can use `BoxLayout` instead of `FloatLayout`. The `BoxLayout` will set the size of its children to fit its available space (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html)). So, perhaps something like this will work:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#6ec4c1")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.95}
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        ImageButton:
            source: "images/back_arrow.png"
            on_release: app.change_screen("home_screen")
        Image:
            source: "images/icon.png"
        Label:
            text: ""
    Image:
        id: banner
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
        # size_hint: 1, None
        source: "images/banner.png"
```

Note that setting `size_hint: 1, 0.05` in the `GridLayout` means that 95% of the `BoxLayout` will be given to the banner.

Comment: This is indeed a fix but if possible I'd like it to scale in y to fit the width could this be done?

Comment: I have modified my answer to do what I think you want.

Comment: I added two pictures to the question in which I explain what is going wrong...

Comment: Another modification of my answer.